# how to load javascript with html fragments into an existing web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm developing a small app designed to embed HTML + JavaScript (JavaScript manages the behavior of HTML) into existing websites.  My small app is an ASP.Net MVC 3 app.  What's the best approach for delivering JavaScript to the web client?  I do not have access to the web clients except for giving them the URL to retrieve the HTML/JavaScript.  The web clients will be retrieving the HTML/JavaScript using jQuery.  jQuery will then load the results of the ASP.Net MVC 3 app into the DOM.  Should the JavaScript that's needed to manage the behavior of the embedded HTML simply be a  at the end of the HTML fragment?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Tell us more about those HTML fragments.

Comment: The HTML fragments is content from a database.  The user interacts with HTML and their input is submitted back to our server and stored in our database.  The JavaScript I need to include with the HTML fragments is used to manage the responses back to our server via jQuery.  So, my asp.net mvc app is generating HTML 5 content and I have Javascript to manage how the end user interacts with HTML.  My question is what's the best approach for including/sending the javascript down to clients.  Thanks

Comment: Does your script make additional AJAX requests or does it POST some data and that's that?

Comment: (Or is there no more server interaction after the initial request?)

Comment: there's the initial request to retrieve the content from server (HTML + Javascript).  User interacts with HTML as much as they like.  Each interactions spawns a response back to the server via a jQuery call to post data.  The app I'm developing is self contained in that it doesn't do anything with the host.  The host only knows how to make the initial call to retrieve html + javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the loading mechanism is in place, and simply inserts the payload of the HTTP request into the DOM somewhere, then including a `<script>` as the last tag in the payload *is* probably the best way to go.

Any DOM elements the script depends on should be ready for use when it is executed, and there isn't anything wrong with that technique that I know of.

You could get more sophisticated, but not without complicating your jQuery loading mechanism.